# Excuse me, I don't wear pointy hats!

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

> There's a guy moving into my neighbourhood. People have seen him
> do some strange, reality-bending things, like materialising objects out
> of thin air and moving things around telekinetically with a wave of his
> hand. **Rumours are spreading that he's a wizard**, a real magic-wielding wizard.
>
> So I went to visit him to ask how he was able to do all that and **ask
> him straight out if he's really a wizard**.
>
> **He promptly denied** and laughed in my face, of course, and then conjured up some cards.
> "**Here, these cards hold the answer. If you really want to know what I really am, just
> shuffle them and you'll get it**", he said.
>
> After examining them for a while, I replied, "I don't get it. Are you sure
> these aren't just some random nonsense cards you just made up?"
>
> He took the cards back and started scribbling something on them, muttering under
> his breath. "Random nonsense cards, huh? How rude! Here, let me show
> you." He drew a line there, crossed something out there, scribbled
> away...
>
> Then after a short while he blurted out, "Hey, you tricked me! I'm not
> going to solve it all for you. Here, three cards are more than enough, you can figure out the other three yourself!
> Don't need to draw on them like I did, that was just a
> guideline - you can do it all in your head. Shuffle them. **Shuffle them all and If you're
> done shuffling then shuffle once more and the answer will be made clear to you.
> It won't spell it out, but you'll know what it implies.**"
>
> And with that, he vanished into thin air, leaving me alone in his
> own house. What a weird guy!

---

<sub>*Bold parts are for TL;DR</sub>

I spent too much time shuffling these cards in every order and still got nowhere. That may not have been the right approach. I don't know…

I give up, Puzzling SE. Please solve it for me. Here are the cards the wizard gave me:

[image: cards]

**What is the wizard's real profession?**

---

Hint:

> Due to ambiguity of its size, the other creature on the third card could potentially have either 6 or 4 lines If lines were to be drawn on it. In this puzzle, it is 4 (and no X mark).

Comment: Are the images AI-generated?

Comment: @1357924680a All the objects (e.g., [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QHDN.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o8qU.png)), the background, and [the blank card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXA69.png) were generated by an AI, yes. Then afterward I put them together using photo-editing software. The fact that they were created by AI does not affect the process of solving the puzzle or the creative process behind it. The puzzle would function the same even if I had used clipart or stock photos of these objects instead.

Comment: However, in that case, they would not have a consistent art style and would not match aesthetically well like it did. That's why I chose to go with the AI.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first thing that stands out is that

> in at least two of the given images, the thing annotated with lines has a name that matches the number of spaces between the lines, so perhaps we are supposed to remove the letter corresponding to the crossed-out space, combine with a word for the *other* thing on the card, and anagram. Probably each card will have one letter to be removed. (And then maybe the removed letters will be significant at the end, most likely anagrammed to make the final answer.)

Well,

> the first one is a DOE on a RAF(T), and Qat tells me that the only anagram of DOERAF is FEDORA. That would fit with the *hats* in the title, so let's continue.

The second card

> is, I think, a TOME on a (B)ARN making a MONTERA.

The third card

> looks like a P(I)PER and a MOUSE, but the hint tells us that it's actually a 3 not a 5 so presumably a RAT, so this is a TRAPPER.

The fourth card

> must be an OWL and a BE(A)R making a BOWLER.

The fifth card

> seems like a PIANO and a CA(R)T making a CAPOTAIN.

The sixth card

> is a (B)AT and a ROBE making a BOATER.

At this point we have

> all the extra letters, and shuffling these we pull a RABBIT out of all those hats, as any good wizard should be able to do. Is our wizard a rabbit? I think not! Rather, I think we have to remove one letter again and find that he is a RABBI. Perhaps his wizardry is [practical Kaballah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_Kabbalah) or something of the kind. Anyway, a rabbi might wear various kinds of hats, but mostly not pointy ones, though in the Middle Ages one might have been seen wearing a so-called [Jewish hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_hat), which is pointy :-).

Comment: Excellent work!

Comment: Spoiler warning. ebg13(Lbh ernyyl chyyrq gur enoov bhg bs gur ung!)